# Requests no flask, para campos com o mesmo nome

Tags: python-3.x, flask

```
  <div>
        {% if filmes|length > 0 %}
        {% for f in filmes %}
        <form action="/pesquisa_filmes_id", method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_filme", name="id_filme" ,value="{{f}}"> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{{f}}</button>
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

```
def pesquisa_filmes_id():
    api_key = 'xxxxxxx'
    id_filme = request.form['id_filme']
    url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey={}&i={}".format(api_key, id_filme)
    retorno_id = requests.get(url).json()
    titulo = id_filme
    diretor = 0
    ano = 0
    url_image = "http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey={0}&i={1}".format(api_key, id_filme)

    return render_template("filme.html", filme = titulo, diretor = diretor, ano = ano, imagem = url_image)
```

Queria retornar o valor de um POST, porém como eles acabam ficando com o mesmo nome, na hora de atribuir no flask, acaba me retornando a variavel vazia.
Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Aparentemente seu codigo esta ok, exibe algum erro? Você setou corretamente o POST no seu route? ex: @app.route('/pesquisa_filmes_id', methods=['POST']) ?

Comment: Meu erro estava no input do HTML, na virgula antes do value.
Isso estava fazendo com que o value fosse anulado.